# Flask blueprint error - Could not build url for endpoint

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am setting up a python/flask app that uses blueprints. I am currently getting the skeletal "hello world" app going, and when it works I will extend it. But I am stuck and getting an error "werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'index'. Did you mean 'main.index' instead?"

My app is based on Miguel Grinberg's "mega Tutorial" and I can't see any difference between my cut down code and his. I have read some documentation and searched for help but nothing quite fits. I think it is the type of error which will be obvious to an expert.

Below I list what I think is the relevant code.

The application structure is

```
\myapp
  myapp.py
  \app
    __init__.py
    \main
      __init__.py
      routes.py
      ...
    \...
      __init__.py
      routes.py
      ...
```

where each subfolder of `\app` will be a blueprint.

```
myapp.py

from app import create_app
app = create_app()
```

```
\app\__init__.py

from flask import Flask, request, current_app
from config import Config

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)

#   Register blueprints
    from app.errors import bp as errors_bp
    app.register_blueprint(errors_bp)

    from app.auth import bp as auth_bp
    app.register_blueprint(auth_bp, url_prefix='/auth')

    from app.meta import bp as meta_bp
    app.register_blueprint(meta_bp)

    from app.main import bp as main_bp
    app.register_blueprint(main_bp)

    return app
```

```
\app\main\__init__.py

from flask import Blueprint

bp = Blueprint('main', __name__)

from app.main import routes
```

```
\app\main\routes.py

from app.main import bp
from flask import render_template


@bp.route('/')
@bp.route('/index')
def index():
    msg = "Hello World!"
    return render_template('index.html', title='Home', msg=msg)
```

An the html template extends base.html and is trivial

```
\app\templates\index.html

{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div><h1>{{ msg }}</h1></div>
{% endblock %}
```

And here is base. html

```
<html>
    <head>
        {% if title %}
            <title>{{ title }} - Metapplica</title>
        {% else %}
            <title>Welcome to Metapplica</title>
        {% endif %}
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            Meta:
            <a href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Home</a>
        </div>
        <hr>
        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
            {% if messages %}
                <ul>
                    {% for message in messages %}
                        <li>{{ message }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

When I open this in a browser I get

"werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'index'. Did you mean 'main.index' instead?"

which implies somehow I am getting my name leveling wrong or?

The full error page is here (slightly different names because I simplified the code a tad).

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "c:\users\markko~1\dropbox\python\projects\metapp~1\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2328, in **call**
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "c:\users\markko~1\dropbox\python\projects\metapp~1\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2314, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "c:\users\markko~1\dropbox\python\projects\metapp~1\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1760, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "c:\users\markko~1\dropbox\python\projects\metapp~1\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py", line 36, in reraise
raise value
File "c:\users\markko~1\dropbox\python\projects\metapp~1\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2311, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "c:\users\markko~1\dropbox\python\projects\metapp~1\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1834, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "c:\users\markko~1\dropbox\python\projects\metapp~1\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1737, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "c:\users\markko~1\dropbox\python\projects\metapp~1\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py", line 36, in reraise
raise value
File "c:\users\markko~1\dropbox\python\projects\metapp~1\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1832, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "c:\users\markko~1\dropbox\python\projects\metapp~1\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1818, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint
File "C:\Users\Mark Kortink\Dropbox\Python\projects\metapplica\app\main\routes.py", line 16, in index
return render_template('index.html', title='Home', msg=msg)
File "c:\users\markko~1\dropbox\python\projects\metapp~1\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 135, in render_template
context, ctx.app)
File "c:\users\markko~1\dropbox\python\projects\metapp~1\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 117, in _render
rv = template.render(context)
File "c:\users\markko~1\dropbox\python\projects\metapp~1\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\asyncsupport.py", line 76, in render
return original_render(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "c:\users\markko~1\dropbox\python\projects\metapp~1\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1008, in render
return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
File "c:\users\markko~1\dropbox\python\projects\metapp~1\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "c:\users\markko~1\dropbox\python\projects\metapp~1\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "C:\Users\Mark Kortink\Dropbox\Python\projects\metapplica\app\templates\index.html", line 1, in top-level template code
{% extends "base.html" %}
File "C:\Users\Mark Kortink\Dropbox\Python\projects\metapplica\app\templates\base.html", line 12, in top-level template code
Home
File "c:\users\markko~1\dropbox\python\projects\metapp~1\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\helpers.py", line 356, in url_for
return appctx.app.handle_url_build_error(error, endpoint, values)
File "c:\users\markko~1\dropbox\python\projects\metapp~1\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2080, in handle_url_build_error
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "c:\users\markko~1\dropbox\python\projects\metapp~1\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py", line 36, in reraise
raise value
File "c:\users\markko~1\dropbox\python\projects\metapp~1\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\helpers.py", line 345, in url_for
force_external=external)
File "c:\users\markko~1\dropbox\python\projects\metapp~1\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\routing.py", line 2007, in build
Open an interactive python shell in this frameraise BuildError(endpoint, values, method, self)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The blueprint you're using is scoped to `main`, so the `url_for()` in base.html needs to reference `main.index`.

Comment: what does "blueprint scoped into main" mean and do i have other options? Is there a way to set things up so I don't have to remember/hardcode the structure of the website into the blueprints? In other words when I render "index.html" i don't want to care if it is "in" main.

Comment: By the way main.index works, and now i look more closely so does Miguel Grinberg's so thanks. I think I need to do some more reading on blueprints!

Comment: Sorry, I was forgetting that that was shorthand for a what may be a complicated idea. See 9.2 (Python Scopes and Namespaces) in https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: Thanks @Dave, i will have a look, i have used classes a fair bit but obviously didn't connect blueprints with namespaces.